# how is repository pattern really done?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, repository-pattern

I'm using elastic search with my asp.net core web api. I don't quite get where the line is drawn when it comes to repository responsibility.

Here is how I have defined my implementations:

```
public SearchRespository: ISearchRespository<Product>
{
   private ElasticClient _client

   public async Task<ISearchResponse<Product>> SearchAsync(ISearchRequest request)
    {
        var response = _client.SearchAsync<Product>(request);
        return await products;
    }        

    . . . // others
}
```

In my controller:

```
public SearchController : Controller
{
    private ISearchRespository _repo;

    public SearchController(ISearchRespository repo)
    {
       _repo = repo;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Search()
    {
       // build my search request from Request.Query

       var response = await _client.SearchAsync(request);
       var model = new SearchModel
       {
           Products = response.Documents;
           Aggregations = response.Aggregations;
       }

       return Ok(model)
}
```

As it stands the repo is passing the elastic response as is. My question is have I drawn my line right? what if I just move `_client` to my controller or move building request and constructing `model` to `_repo`? how do you guys get your repository right?

Comment: I would suggest you ask this question in codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, the purpose of the repository is to abstract away the persistence. I assume that `ISearchResponse` and `ISearchRequest` are elastic search interfaces. They should not be defined on `ISearchRespository`, because then your persistence leaks into your business/domain layer. Here you should use your own classes or if your search requests are simple enough, use the method parameters for it. When your persistence types leak into your domain, the repository is of little use except for DRY

Comment: my search requests are quite involved, I have defined helper classes to build them. So you are suggesting I let my `repo` returns my `SearcModel` and let those helpers help my `repo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you use Elastic Search should be an implementation detail that especially the controller shouldn't know about, so you are absolutely right in abstracting this away from the controller. I often look at the SOLID principles to get a sense whether I'm on the right track or not. If we look at the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), you'll see that it guides us towards a style that is also known as [Ports and Adapters](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture), which basically means that the use of an external tool is abstracted away (the port), and on the boundary of the application you implement an [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that connects to that third party.

So from the sense of the Dependency Inversion Principle, you're on the right track.

There is however a lot of misunderstanding of what [Martin Fowler's Repository Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) is trying to solve. The definition is as follows:

> Mediates between the **domain** and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.

Important to note here is that a repository is intended to be used by the domain layer.

There is however a lot of misuse of the repository pattern, because many developers start to use it as a grouping structure for queries. The repository is -as I see it- not intended for all queries in the system; but only for queries that are the *domain* needs. These queries support the domain in making decisions for the mutations on the system.

Most queries that your system requires however are not this kind of query. Your code is a good example, since in this case you skip the domain completely and only do a read operation.

This is something that is not suited for the repository. We can verify this by comparing it with the SOLID principles again.

Let's say we have the following repository interface:

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    User[] FindUsersBySearchText(string searchText, bool includeInactiveUsers);
    User[] GetUsersByRoles(string[] roles);
    UserInfo[] GetHighUsageUsers(int reqsPerDayThreshold);
    // More methods here
}
```

This is a typical repository abstraction that you'll see developers write. Such abstraction is problematic from perspective of the SOLID principles, because:

- The Interface Segregation Principle is violated, because the interfaces are wide (have many methods) and consumers of those interfaces are forced to depend on methods that they don’t use.
- The Single Responsibility Principle is violated, because the methods in the repository implementation are not highly cohesive. The only thing that relates those methods is the fact that they belong to the same concept or entity.
- The design violates the Open/Closed Principle, because almost every time a query is added to the system, an existing interface and its implementations need to be changed. Every interface has at least two implementations: one real implementation and one test implementation.

A design like this also causes a lot of pain down the road, because it becomes hard to apply cross-cutting concerns (like security, auditing, logging, caching, etc) down the line.

So this is not something the Repository pattern is intended to solve; such design is just a big SOLID violation.

The solution here is to model queries separately in your system and not use a repository *at all*. There are many articles written about this, and you can read my take on this [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

If I look at your design, it actually has some resemblance with the design I'm promoting here, since you seem to have a generic query method that can handle many type of queries. The query message (your `ISearchRequest`) seems however specific to Elastic Search. This is something you should strive to prevent, as the Dependency Inversion Principle states.

Comment: I'm still finding my way around your blog post. Quite an insightful read. quick question, in my case I'm building elastic `search request`, rather than passing the `searchText`, so in your case where will you put such a logic? `IQuery<TResult>` or `IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>`?

Comment: @no0b: I'm not sure I understand your question? The TQuery is the definition of what is possible to ask (the message containing the search criteria). Using the TQuery, the IQueryHandler will execute the search and will build up the TResult.

Comment: I'm still at the beginning parts of `a better design` :). but what I meant is `FindUsersBySearchTextQuery.SearchText` is a search text passed to a `controller` and used to search user names that contains it. with elastic you  ought to built elastic `SearchRequest` model from `SearchTest` to use with `_client.SearchAsync(searchRequest)`, so my question is would you do that in `FindUsersBySearchTextQuery` or `FindUsersBySearchTextQueryHandler` or somewhere else.

Comment: `FindUsersBySearchTextQuery` is merely the object that contains information about the search. These could be IDs, search text, or what ever comes directly from the UI. It is the `FindUsersBySearchTextQueryHandler`s job to do the search based on the input data, including possible transformation to something that your search engine understands.

Comment: thanks. wondering why I didn't come across your blog well in time. Now I might have to redo a lot on my code. :(

Comment: You can solve most of the potential problems with Repository cited in this answer by combining it with the DDD design pattern Specification. You can learn more about Specification here: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/patterns-library  It seems to me that specification would also be a good fit for the OP's problem.

Comment: @Steven I did't quite get your final verdict when it comes to a consumer getting a number of `IHandlers<,>`'s vs a consumer getting 1 `IQueryProcessor`. By the look of things, I might have four or so `Handlers<,>`'s

Comment: @no0b: What is it you want to know?

Comment: @Steven Would you suggest abstracting away ElasticSearch (or whatever search library) behind something like an ISearchProvider interface (similar to your ILogger example elsewhere), or using it directly in the Domain level Query Handlers? My concern with adding an ISearchProvider is that the IElasticClient is already providing most of its functionality via extension methods which would have to be replicated. Using an IElasticClient at the QueryHandler level still simplifies what the controllers need to send down to a string, but doesn't require (re)writing a huge middleware layer.

Comment: @Necoras: It doesn't seem useful to try to hide this technology from your query handlers. Your query handler implementations are always dependent on data technology (such as ORM, database or web service) and from perspective of the DIP, those handlers are adapters on the boundary of the application. From that perspective, it's obvious that a query handler will depend directly on elastic search without an intermediate layer.